Is it correct to say "go to his home" so we don't worry if he is living in a flat or a house?
My friend is living in a flat not a house.
Can I say "I have to go to his home today" instead of  "I have to go to his flat today"?
If we use "home", we don't worry if he is living in a flat or a house.

If you know his address, you know if it's house or flat. Home is more abstract. "What a home you've made for yourself!" "Ugh. You call this home?" "Home is where the heart is."

I would normally just say “I have to go to his place today.”
I wouldn’t use “home” like in your example; it feels like it creates a weird emphasis on it being his home.

The place where you live is your home, no matter whether it is a house, a flat, a boat or a caravan!

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Then I must have misunderstood the point of the question.
